# Python project structure for tree with many different nodes

Tags: python, tree, structure

So, I am implementing a data tree in python that represents mathematic expressions much like this [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).
Each node represents an operation (+, *, exp(), ...) and each leaf represents a number or variable. Therefore I created a module *Expression.py*, that contains a parent class *Node* and child classes for mathematical operations.

Now, as the project becomes more complex, I am starting to implement more and more node types to cover more operations and each child class of *Node* is starting to have quite a lot methods for tasks as term simplification etc.

So far, I implemented all of these child nodes in the *Expression.py* file. But it is by now a 500+ lines file and I am not even done yet. I tried to split it up by putting each child class into a single file (Java style) and merging all of them in one package, which would match my understanding of correct structure. But this implementation is giving me problems as the different modules like *Addition.py* and *Multiplication.py* still reference each other. E.g. an *Addition*-object's method might return a *Multiplication*-object and vice versa.

My question is: How do you structure such a project? How to structure many related child classes that reference each other besides putting them in a single huge file?

If I arrange them in a package, how would I import them properly? And how would I reference them properly?

**Edit:**
Ok, let me be more specific, this is some sample code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def derive(self):
        pass


class Sine(Node):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def derive(self):
        return Cosine(self.arg)

class Cosine(Node):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def derive(self):
        return Multiplication(Num(-1), Sine(self.arg))

class Multiplication:
      ...
```

As you see the classes *Sine* and *Cosine* have a circular dependency, that I cannot (knowingly) split into two seperate files. Though I do not want to put thousands of lines of child classes into one file. This is only sample code. The classes actually consist of way more lines.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't show any code, it is only possible to give a general answer. First of all, between putting everything in one file and each class in a single file, you have the option to put groups of classes in modules. I doubt that all your classes depend on each other. So you need to get a better understanding of the structure of your dependencies. If you understand the structure, Python will offer you the tools to express this structure in code. Mixins, decorators, meta classes, ... are powerful tools to express complex structures without violating DRY. So my advice would be: Try to understand your structure better!